# Infrastructure for Running your Zend Queue Receiver

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, zend-queue

I have a simple messaging queue setup and running using the [Zend_Queue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html) object heirarchy.  I'm using a [Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.adapters.html#zend.queue.adapters.configuration.Db) back-end.  I'm interested in using this as a job queue, to schedule things for processing at a later time. They're jobs that don't need to happen immediately, but should happen sooner rather than later.

Is there a best-practices/standard way to setup your infrastructure to run jobs?  I understand the code for receiving a message from the queue, but what's not so clear to me is how run the program that does that receiving.  A cron that receives n messages on the command-line, run once a minute?  A cron that fires off multiple web requests, each web request running the receiver script? Something else?

Tangential bonus question.  If I'm running other queries with Zend_Db, will the message queue queries be considered part of that transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like a thread pool. Create a command line php script to handle the receiving. It should be started by a shell script that automatically restarts the process if it dies. The shell script should not start the process if it is already running (use a $pid.running file or similar). Have cron run several of these every 1-10 minutes. That should handle the receiving nicely.

I wouldn't have the cron fire a web request unless your cron is on another server for some strange reason.

Another way to use this would be to have some backround process creating data, and a web user(s) consume it as they naturally browse the site. A report generator might work this way. Company-wide reports are available to all users but you don't want them all generating this db/time intensive report. So you create a queue and process one at a time possible removing duplicates. All users can view the report(s) when ready.

[According to the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.adapters.html#zend.queue.adapters.configuration.Db) it doens't look like the zend db is even using the same connection as your other zend_db queries. But of course the best way to find out is to make a simple test.

**EDIT**
The multiple lines in the cron are for concurrency. each line represents a worker for the pool. I was not clear, you don't want the pid as the identifier, you want to pass that as a parameter.

- - - - - /home/byron/run_queue.sh Process1
- - - - - /home/byron/run_queue.sh Process2
- - - - - /home/byron/run_queue.sh Process3

The bash script would check for the $process.running file if it finds it exit.

otherwise:

- Create the $process.running file.
- start the php process. Block/wait until finished.
- Delete the $process.running file.

This allows for the php script to die but not cause the pool to loose a worker.

If the queue is empty the php script exits immediately and is started again by the nex invocation of cron.

Comment: Follow up questions; (apologies if this is naive/obvious). Are you suggesting I

1. Write a PHP program to receive the messages;

2. Write a shell script that looks for a $pid.running file created by, the PHP script?;

3. If the $pid.running file isn't found kick off the PHP script and then, exit?;

4. Have many lines in the crontab for kicking off the shell script. Some of these will run, see the $pid.running file and exit, but by having multiple attempts running each minute, you ensure a constant running/re-running of the program at a regular basis;

Do I have it, or am I missing something?

Comment: I also forgot, you can also set a timeout on the running file by looking at its creation date.. You would need to have your php scripts process only x number of entries and exit so you would know how long the longest running script would take.

Comment: Ah ha, I thought I was missing something.  Thanks for taking the time to explain that in newbie levels of detail for me!